# toggling image classes for inactive/active states

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still coming up against resistance here with my js-  i have a row of thumbnails. The first starts with an active class,the others have inactive classes. On click, i want the thumb clicked to switch to active and the previous to go inactive. I also want a hover effect for the inactive classes. Right now, I can add the active class, but i cant figure out how to toggle the prev active class

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".groomsmen_thumbs, .bridesmaid_thumbs").click(function(){
if ( $(this).find(".toplevel").hasClass("inactivethumb") ) {
$('img', this).toggleClass("activethumb inactivethumb");

}
}),

$('.groomsmen_thumbs, .bridesmaid_thumbs')
.on("mouseenter", function() {
$(this).find(".inactivethumb.toplevel").animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
})
.on("mouseleave", function() {
$(this).find(".inactivethumb.toplevel").animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");

})
});
```

links look like this

```
<li><a href="#" class="groomsmen_thumbs"><img src="images/groom_thumb1_0.jpg"/><img class="toplevel activethumb" src="images/groom_thumb1_1.jpg"/></a></li>
```

Comment: you are also missing some semicolons after your functions.

Answer (score 0):

try to use jquery's active and prev:

js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var active = $(".active");
var next = active.next('img');
active.click(function(){
    active.removeAttr('class');
    next.addClass('active');
    });
})
```

html :

```
<ul>
<li>
<img src="1.jpg" class="active"/>
<img src="2.jpg" class=""/>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) is adding both inactivethumb and activethumb class. You want something like [switchClass](http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/) (jQuery UI), if you are using that. Here is an alternative with regular jQuery:

```
$(".groomsmen_thumbs, .bridesmaid_thumbs").click(function(){
var toplevel = $(this).find(".toplevel");
if(toplevel.hasClass("inactivethumb")
{
 toplevel.removeClass("inactivethumb").addClass("activethumb");
}
});
```

A shorter alternative, assuming all imgs start with `inactivethumb` class:

```
$(".groomsmen_thumbs, .bridesmaid_thumbs").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".toplevel").toggleClass("inactivethumb").toggleClass("activethumb");
    });
```

This will remove the `inactive` class and add the `activeclass` on `click`.